# Facing an error that an id statement is required for multi-state models while running cox model in R

Tags: r, regression, survival, cox

i am trying to run cox regression model in R studio but facing same error every time.

```
cox.model <-coxph(Surv(dat$los, dat$died) ~ gender, data=dat)
Error in coxph(Surv(dat$los, dat$died) ~ gender, data = dat) : 
  an id statement is required for multi-state models
```

Here is data:

[image]

Comment: What's the class of `died`? e.g. with `class(dat$died)`. If it's a factor then `Surv` treats it as a multi-state model. Try converting it to an integer if its a factor with `dat$died <- as.integer(dat$died)` and try running again. Note you don't need the `dat$` in the `Surv` function, as it by default looks in the data object from coxph